# Google search console URL removal tool, cancel requests for over 1000 URL

Tags: google-search-console, url-removal

I have entered about 2000 urls in the google search console url removal tool. I need to cancel them but only have access to the last 1000.  Is there a way I can access the 100 first entries.

I have canceled the 1000 showing in the hope that they would place to the first 1000 but with no luck.

I have tried sorting and filtering on page. The sorting only affects the 1000 items. Filtering on the page also only afftects the 1000 items returned.

I was wondering if there way a way to pass some filtering in the URL. Whether it is requested, status or URL. This could show the URLs I am looking for.